# What is '-1[p]' when p points to an array (of int) index?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, unary-operator, postfix-operator

Today I stumbled over a C riddle that got a new surprise for me.

I didn't think that -1[p] in the example below would compile, but it did. In fact, x ends up to be -3.

```
    int x;
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int *p = &array[1];
    x = -1[p];
```

I searched the internet for something like -1[pointer] but couldn't find anything. Okay, it is difficult to enter the correct search query, I admit. Who knows why -1[p] compiles and X becomes -3?

Comment: It's the same as `-(p[1])` which is the same as `-(array[2])`.

Comment: The riddle has two levels: to understand it, first you must know that `a[5] == 5[a]`. But if you haven't also memorized C's less-than-intuitive precedence rules, or if you don't remember that C treats `-1` as an application of the unary minus operator (instead of treating it as a single token and an intrinsically negative constant), you might be fooled into thinking that `-1[p]` is the same as `p[-1]` rather than `-(p[1])`.

Comment: And of course it binds lower than indexing because otherwise the sane looking `-p[1]` would try to negate a pointer ...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was about to vote for the `a[5] == 5[a]` one as a dup, too, but it really only covers half of this question.  I'd say the surprising precedence here is equally significant.

Comment: @SteveSummit I am not sure why precedence is so surprising and deserves a whole 5-answer question. Yes, it can be a bit confusing, but it is a very basic thing, especially given the results of the code execution..

Comment: @JL2210 Unlike how it is in more sensible languages, C programmers actually need to be able to solve these kinds of riddles in order to do their actual jobs.

Comment: @zwol But the least a programmer could do would be to write `-(1[p])` or `-p[1]` if it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 28):

I'm the person that made this "riddle" (see [my Twitter post](https://twitter.com/Lun_rLambda/status/1161595413255872512))

So! What's up with -1[p]?

ISO C actually defines [] to be symmetrical, meaning `x[y]` is the same as `y[x]`, where x and y are both expressions.

Naively, we could jump to the conclusion that `-1[p]` is therefore `p[-1]` and so `x = 1`,
However, -1 is actually the unary minus operator applied to the constant 1, and unary minus has a lower precedence than []

So, `-1[p]` is `-(p[1])`, which yields -3.

This can lead to funky looking snippets like this one, too:

`sizeof(char)["abc"] /* yields 'b' */`

Answer (score 12):

First thing to figure out is the precedence. Namely `[]` has higher precedence than unary operators, so `-1[p]` is equal to `-(1[p])`, not `(-1)[p]`. So we're taking the result of `1[p]` and negating it.

`x[y]` is equal to `*(x+y)`, so `1[p]` is equal to `*(1+p)`, which is equal to `*(p+1)`, which is equal to `p[1]`.

So we're taking the element one after where `p` points, so the third element of `array`, i.e. 3, and then negating it, which gives us `-3`.

Answer (score 10):

According to the C Standard (6.5.2 Postfix operators) the subscript operator is defined the following way

```
postfix-expression [ expression ]
```

So before the square brackets there shall be a postfix expression.

In this expression statement

```
x = -1[p];
```

there is used the postfix expression `1` (that is at the same time a primary expression), the postfix expression `1[p]` (that is the subscript operator) and the unary operator `-` Take into account that when the compiler splits a program into tokens then integer constants are considered as tokens themselves without the minus. minus is a separate token.

So the statement can be rewritten like

```
x = -( 1[p] );
```

because a postfix expression has a higher priority than an unary expression.

Let's consider at first the postfix sub-expression `1[p]`

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So this sub-expression evaluates like `*( ( 1 ) + ( p ) )` and is the same as `*( ( p ) + ( 1 ) ).`

Thus the above statement

```
x = -1[p];
```

is equivalent to

```
x = -p[1];
```

and will yield `-3`, because the pointer `p` points to the second element of the array due to the statement

```
int *p = &array[1];
```

and then the expression `p[1]` yields the value of the element after the second element of the array. Then the unary operator `-` is applied.

Answer (score 7):

This

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

looks like

```
array[0]   array[1]  array[2]
 --------------------------
|     1   |    2    |   3  | 
 --------------------------
 0x100     0x104     0x108   <-- lets assume 0x100 is base address of array
array
```

Next when you do like

```
int *p = &array[1];
```

the integer pointer `p` points to address  of `array[1]` i.e `0x104`. It looks like

```
array[0]   array[1]  array[2]
 --------------------------
|     1   |    2    |   3  | 
 --------------------------
 0x100     0x104     0x108   <-- lets assume 0x100 is base address of array
             |
            p holds 0x104
```

And when you do like

```
x = -1[p]
```

`-1[p]` is equivalent to `-(1[p])` i.e `-(p[1])`. it looks like

```
-(p[1]) ==> -(*(p + 1*4)) /* p holds points to array[1] i.e 0x104 */
        ==> -(*(0x104 + 4))
        ==> -(*(0x108)) ==> value at 0x108 is 3
        ==> prints -3
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is really interesting.

p[n] means `*(p+n)`. Thats why you see 3, because "p" points to array[1] which is 2, and -p[1] is interpreted as `-(*(p+1))` which is -3.